# I left off a detail in the results section of a manuscript that's been accepted. How do I remedy this?

Tags: publications, statistics

In a manuscript recently accepted to a journal, I just realized I neglected to mention that I centered a variable for an analysis. How crucial is this detail to correct, and what's the best way to go about doing it?

Comment: If the manuscript has already gone into production, it is difficult to make any more changes. But, if it is going to be accepted, then it is possible. In both the cases, you can write an email to the editor; however, in the former, it is difficult and in the latter it is easy.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to the specifics of the correction you need to make, but in general, I would think that you make the change as you revise it for the final version, and note the change in the cover letter to the editor.  If it is something significant enough that it could affect the decision to accept, the editor might send it back to reviewers to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the severity of the changes, you may be able to make them at the proof reading stage.

However, from what you say, it appears that the editor should be consulted, as the change may very well affect the interpretation of your results and hence the editorial decision. In such a case (or if you're unsure), you should contact the editor immediately and ask for advise.